# Testing using Moq, a line uses async queryable extensions and project, how to test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, automapper

I have this method (partial method)

```
public async Task<List<UserDto>> GetUsers(Guid accountId)
{
    using (var context = this.contextFactory.Create())
    {
        var users = await context.Users
            .Where(u => u.AccountId.Equals(accountId))
            .Project()
            .To<UserDto>()
            .ToListAsync();

        // I don't care about the above bit of code and whether it works

        // I care about this code doing what it says it does.
        if (users == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("there are no users");
        }
    }
}
```

So I mock out my context factory, I mock out my context and I mock out the `DbSet`. I have do some extra stuff:

```
var data = new List<User>
    {
        It.IsAny<User>(),
        It.IsAny<User>(),
        It.IsAny<User>(),
        It.IsAny<User>()
    };
var mockedDbSet = new Mock<IDbSet<User>>();
mockedDbSet.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<User>>().Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator()).Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<User>(data.GetEnumerator()));
mockedDbSet.As<IQueryable<User>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<User>(data.Provider));
mockedDbSet.As<IQueryable<User>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
mockedDbSet.As<IQueryable<User>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
mockedDbSet.As<IQueryable<User>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());
```

So that allows `async` extension methods to be use, like `FirstOrDefaultAsync()`. But for some reason, even after I specifiy mappings for it (cause that threw an error at first) but now it throws a null reference exception when it tries to query the `DbSet`.

I just want to by pass this part so I can get on and test my code works.

So my act is:

```
Exception exception;

try
{
    this.userService.GetUsers(Guid.NewGuid());
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    exception = ex;
}
```

My Assert:

```
Assert.IsNotNull(exception);
Assert.AreEqual(exception.Message, "there are no users");
```

So how do you get all this to play nice and prevent me from getting stuck at my act!

Comment: Is there a way to add support for .Project().To<MyType>()? The conversion is take care of by AutoMapper. This fails when you have Project().To<MyType>() in your code.

System.NotSupportedException: This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is, it may be worth creating a new question about it

Comment: I suspect that you are having the same error. Your code doesn't get to the if (users == null) because the errors happens in the .Project().To<UserDto>() of  the code above. 

        var users = await context.Users
            .Where(u => u.AccountId.Equals(accountId))
            .Project()
            .To<UserDto>()
            .ToListAsync();

Comment: Have you got your async IQueryable's mocked out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that

```
var data = new List<User>
    {
        It.IsAny<User>(),
        It.IsAny<User>(),
        It.IsAny<User>(),
        It.IsAny<User>()
    };
```

Makes my `.Project()` on the query return null reference exception. This is easily fixed by just using `new User()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Don't write this test, it doesn't provide any value. You'd still write an integration test, and this test is far too coupled to the internal implementation of both the controller and data source.

If anything, you'd create an in-memory DbSet stub implementation that backs a collection of objects. But since this doesn't actually hit the production LINQ provider, you'd still write the integration test, negating any value this test would have.

In short, don't try to do what you're doing here, it's not worth any positive gains, and leads to a false sense of worth of these sort of tests.

Comment: I'm not trying to test that bit of code, I'm actually just trying to bypass it so I can test the code that I wrote, obviously I don't give a monkeys about whether project works. I just want it return a list of mapped user dtos so that I can test the rest of my method... if that makes sense. I'll update my question